# Global variables stored as 0 javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, global

This seems like it should be a relatively easy thing, but I can't figure out why it is happening. I am trying to declare two values based on text input to use in further calculations, but every time the results are displayed it shows them as 0.

```
var valOne = document.getElementById("value1").value;
var valTwo = document.getElementById("value2").value;

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function add(){
        var added = +valueOne + +valueTwo;
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = added;
    }, true);
```

When I place the first two lines within the add() function it works fine.

This is a part of a larger issue where I am trying to have the results of calculations display as the two inputted values are typed, if that helps to clear things up as to what I'm searching for. I apologize if this is a duplicate question, and please let me know if you need any other information! I feel like I have tried everything to debug it, but I'm sure the answer is right in front of me and I'm just missing it.

Comment: There's no need for a named function here, btw

Comment: @SterlingArcher It might help for debugging.

Comment: @lonesomeday eh, I can't really name a scenario where a named function as a callback helped me debug (in fact, I don't think I've ever done that)

Comment: @SterlingArcher It means the function has a `name` property, which helps with stacktraces. It won't help *here*, but it's not a bad habit, if a slightly idiosyncratic one.

Comment: @lonesomeday just learned that in the JS chat, that's some handy knowledge, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only storing the current value of those elements:

```
var valOne = document.getElementById("value1").value;
var valTwo = document.getElementById("value2").value;
```

You need to store the elements rather than the value of each element.

```
var elemOne = document.getElementById("value1"); // Store the element
var elemTwo = document.getElementById("value2"); // Store the element
```

Use the object `Number` to convert to number those values.

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function add(){
    // Now use the entered value as number.
    var added = Number(elemOne.value) + Number(elemTwo.value); 
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = added;
}, true);
```

**Aside note:**

You don't need to set a name to the handler:

```
         +--- This is unnecessary.
         | 
         v
function add(){...}
```

You can pass the function/handler as follow:

```
function(){...}
```

> Get the innerHTML to update and display the new result as the input values are typed (without having to click a button or refresh)

Use the event `input` to capture the changes over those elements.

```js
var elemOne = document.getElementById("value1");
var elemTwo = document.getElementById("value2");
var total = document.getElementById("total");

function calculate() {
  total.textContent = (Number(elemOne.value) + Number(elemTwo.value)).toFixed(2);
}

[elemOne, elemTwo].forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('input', calculate);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="value1" placeholder="Enter a number">
<p>
  <input type="number" id="value2" placeholder="Enter a number">
  <h1>
  Total:
  </h1>
  <hr>
  <h2 id="total">0</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! Any tips for how to get it to display dynamically? I'm a JS newbie, as you can probably tell.

Comment: @WashU you're welcome.  What do you mean with *display dynamically?*

Comment: Probably using the wrong phrasing here, but I meant to get the innerHTML to update and display the new result as the input values are typed (without having to click a button or refresh).

Comment: @WashU got it, hold on over there for a minute `:)`

Comment: That was incredibly helpful, I have tried so many "onkeypress" combinations to no avail. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

When your script would be executed `valOne` and `valTwo` would be zero, since on the load of your html page both input elements, `value1` and `value2` would be empty.

On the other hand, it's almost certain that when you click the add button, your input elements have values, so you read those values, if you place your code inside your event listener.

That you can do is to hold a reference to your input elements:

```
var elmOne = document.getElementById("value1");
var elmTwo = document.getElementById("value2");
```

and then read the `value` attribute inside your event listener.

Comment: @tadman Before the click, the `document.getElementById(..)` have already been executed.